# C# webservice not responding to API request if it is running as windows service

Tags: c#

I have an application which can run as an app or as a windows service.
When starting, I open a port and start the webservice with the following code:

```
        try
        {
            CSServiceInstance lovClient = CSServiceInstance.Instance;
            WebHttpBinding lovBinding = new WebHttpBinding();

            movServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(lovClient, new Uri($"http://localhost:{mivPort}"));

            movServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(CSIService), lovBinding, "");
            movServiceHost.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                CSServiceInstance lovClient = CSServiceInstance.Instance;
                WebHttpBinding lovBinding = new WebHttpBinding();

                movServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(lovClient, new Uri($"http://localhost:{mivPort}"));

                movServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(CSIService), lovBinding, "");
                AddURLACL();
                movServiceHost.Open();
                return true;
            }

    private void AddURLACL()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process lovProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo lovStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        lovStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        lovStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        lovStartInfo.Arguments = $"/C netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:{mivPort}/ user=%USERDOMAIN%\\%USERNAME%";
        lovStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        lovProcess.StartInfo = lovStartInfo;
        lovProcess.Start();
        lovProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
```

I Then have a few API calls than can be made, one of them being a state that is returned

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/API/health/status", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string ReturnState();
```

This works perfectly if I run the application as an app, but when I run it as a windows service, it doesn't respond. There isn't even a timeout, if I request the status, it's just stuck on loading. The ReturnState() method is never called.

I have attached a debugger to the startup of the windows service, and I'm getting no exceptions. It is behaving the same way as it is doing as an app.
Commenting out the actual functionality of the application, just leaving the webservice did nothing, neither did changing the port.

I checked with TCPView if the port is being opened, and it is.

The exact same code is used in other applications, and this is the only one that becomes unresponsive when running it as a windows service.

Comment: Not sure about this, but it reminds me of a problem i had with HttpListener. Could you try changing to `new Uri($"http://+:{mivPort}")`?

Comment: Didn't work, got the following error message:
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.